# Слова "распространение" и "снаряжение" — какие корни?

Tags: словообразование

Какой корень в слове "распространение"? А также в слове "снаряжение". Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Какой корень в слове ***распространение***?

Всё зависит от того, как мы определяем корень, как мы его должны определять. В сознании носителей языка **корень – это та часть слова,** которая лежит в его основе (а также в основе родственных слов) и значение которой определяется в современном языке без привлечения этимологии.

Ясное дело, что словообразование здесь такое: **сторона – рас/про/стран/и/ть – рас/про/стран/ени/е** (значение слова: расширить во все стороны, чередование ОРО/РА).

Слово  ***сторона*** известно с XI века (земля, край, бок), о.-с. storna, и.-е. корень  ster/ stor – расширять.

Поэтому корень в слове ***распространение*** – это  ***стран***, и он **не зависит от конкретного словаря**. **Вот это важно для школьников,** которые  должны не просто механически пользоваться словарями, но  развивать логическое мышление, иметь свое мнение и отстаивать его при необходимости. Тогда это будет полезное для них занятие, а не просто придуманное педагогами упражнение.

Вы говорите, что корень ***простран*** или ***распростран***?  Тогда укажите определение корня, которым вы пользуетесь.  Это слово не имеет отношение к слову ***сторона***? Вы в этом уверены? А к чему тогда оно имеет отношение?

Какой корень в слове ***снаряжение***?

Эта задача будет потруднее. Снаряд/и/ть – снаряж/ени/е. Снарядить – это снабдить всем необходимым, подготовить для отправки куда-л.

Конечно, мы догадываемся, что **исторический корень** – это ***ряд***, но его связь со ***снаряжением*** ясно не прослеживается. ***Ряд*** в нашем понимании – совокупность однородных предметов, расположенных по порядку, друг за другом, в одну линию. Но старшее значение у слова ***ряд***  – **правильный строй, порядок, суд, договор,** сравнить: **судить да рядить**.

***Нарядить*** – хорошо одеть, привести **в порядок**, отсюда ***наряд***. А снарядить – это уже **со**брать в дорогу, снабдить всем необходимым. Общая словообразовательная цепочка существует, но она не просматривается однозначно и понятно, поэтому **приставки лучше отнести к корню**, когда мы разбираем слово ***снаряжение***.

Answer (score 0):

> Какой корень в слове "распространение"?

В современном русском языке в разных словарях у разных авторов имеют место такие варианты корня:

1. ***"стран"*** (Баранов; Панов и Текучев; Ефремова и Кузнецова);
2. ***"простран"*** (Морковкин);
3. ***"распростран"*** (Тихонов; Попова и Зайкова).

В первом случае однокоренными с *распространением* словами можно считать слова *страна, сторона*… Безударную гласную в корне можно проверить, к примеру, словоформой *стрАны.*

Во втором случае безударную гласную в корне можно проверить, к примеру, однокоренным с *распространением* словом *прострАнный*.

А вот в третьем случае однокоренными с *распространением* словами безударную гласную в корне проверить не получится, ибо во всех однокоренных с этим словом словах корень оказывается безударным: *распространИть, распространИтель, распространЁнный…*

И потому в орфографических целях наиболее целесообразно, на мой взгляд, в слове ***распространение*** считать корнем или ***стран***, или ***простран.***

Comment: В современных словарях - простран- , от пространять, однокоренное - пространство; снаряж-.(снаряд)

Comment: @Людмила а что за "пространять"?